# How to Sort a Generic Collection With a Where Clause

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-order-by

I am using an `IEnumerable` as the dataSource for a `Repeater` control. I need to sort the `IEnumerable` **WHERE** an entities property value equals a given value, then **ORDER BY** some other value. In other words, I want to sort an `IEnumerable` after some selected entity.

I am guessing I will have to implement the IComparer interface, but not sure where to start. Perhaps it could be as simple as having 2 `IEnumerables;` one with the entity I want displayed first, a second with the other entities, then concatenate them.

```
 Dim myEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of myEntity) = dbContext.myEntity

 myEnumerable.OrderBy(Function(x) x.propertyA **where x.propertyA = "value"**) _
    .OrderBy(function(x) x.propertyB)
```

For simplicity of an example, I will use an `IEnumerable(of String)`

```
  Dim myEnumerable As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"1", "2", "3", "40", "50"}

  myEnumerable.OrderBy(Function(x) where x = "3" Then Order By x.length)
```

I am looking for the resulting sort to be

- 3
- 1
- 2
- 40
- 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
Dim query = myEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x = "3").Concat(myEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x <> "3").OrderBy(Function(x) x)).ToList()
```

C# Equivalent:-

```
var query = myEnumerable.Where(x => x == "3").Concat(myEnumerable.Where(x => x != "3").OrderBy(x => x)).ToList();
```